# Is there a way to "npm init" an ES module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, es6-modules

All modern versions of Node need to run packages as modules is `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, but I don't see any flags for `npm init` or `yarn init` that will add that property.

Is there a flag for either package manager *or* an easy way to add the value to `package.json` (i.e., `npm package-property set type module` or something similar)?

Comment: With npm you can customize the questions asked and fields created during the `npm init` process, as described in the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file#customizing-the-packagejson-questionnaire).

Comment: `type` is not a standard field in `package.json`.
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: @RobC I am generating project directories with `yarn`, so just setting my own local preference will not work. Worst case scenario, I can read package.json, modify it, and write it back. The question is whether I can do this easily, in the shell, using `npm` or `yarn`, in a way that does not involve just reading `package.json` and handling it myself.

Comment: @hong4rc [Support was added for the `type` field in 2019.](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field). The question was not "Should I put a `type` field in my package.json?"

Comment: @Christian - Yes, the `type` field is currently _experimental_ and who knows it may just be temporary - hence why npm hasn't formally listed as a "standard" field. Personally, I (like many others) don't use the _experimental_ ESM syntax in production code.

Comment: @RobC Thankfully, none of this is production code. That field just tells Node to use the `--experimental_modules` flag and process ES6 modules. Like I said, it is not a concern.

Answer (score 11):

This does exactly what you asked:

`npm init es6`

It creates a `package.json` with the `"type": "module"` setting.

source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-es6

Comment: This annoyingly sets `"license": "AGPL-version-3.f0",`

Answer (score 9):

Saw this question a while ago, and for the longest time I used "npm init esnext". I just figured out how to edit package.json keys directly from the command line:

```bash
npm init -y; npm pkg set type="module";
```

Although the first command will log the content of `package.json` without `"type": "module"` to the console, if you open `package.json` you will see that it has been added properly by the second command.

Comment: What do you mean by "it will appear incorrect"?

Comment: @user3064538 I edited the answer to clarify what the original author meant (which I figured out by running the commands myself)

Answer (score 1):

While @stackoverflow221's answer is good, it adds the `type` at the end of the `package.json`, which feels slightly unnatural to me.

I prefer to put the `type` right above the `entry`, given they are closely related.

For that, I have the following bash function on my `.bashrc`, but it should be easy to adapt to any shell configuration:

```bash
# custom 'npm init'
# - runs regular 'npm init', interactively
# - then, if successful, add "type": "module" to the generated package.json,
# - right above the line containing "main".
function npm-init () {
  npm init 

  # if package.json was not created, exit (this means the user cancelled)
  # (npm init has no error codes)
  if [[ ! -f package.json ]]; then
    return 1
  fi

  sed -i '/"main":/i\  "type": "module",' package.json
}
```

Then, just run `npm-init` instead of `npm init`

Answer (score -1):

For ES compatible modules there exists `create-esm` package. Among other things ([docs](https://github.com/standard-things/esm)) it also populates module field.

So it seems you could use `npm init esm`.

Comment: Note, if you come here seeking the same ask as in OP, i.e., any flags for npm init or yarn init that will add that `"type": "module"` property in package.json, then this is not the answer. It just adds `esm` into dependencies, which is not what I wanted. YMMW.

Comment: Now it's 2022 and this answer may very well be the best possible answer, but it's still horrible.  Node.js and all the other laggards really need to get their act together and kick commonjs/require to the curb.  This pain has been going on for way too many years.

Comment: This apparently does not add `"type": "module"` to package.json. See the selected answer instead.

Comment: 25 years ago perl was dominant and most of the pain came from the garbage module system and the fact that types were a bolt-on.  Some things never change

Answer (score -1):

You could set default values when running `pnpm init`

```
npm config set init.type module
```